Total cost of adding a new partner to company license
We want to add a new person to our trade license, what will be the total cost including their visa charges, labor chargers etc

What is a "trade license" ? What entity or person issued this license" What country are you asking about?

To get an answer you’ll need to provide more details about the problem you need help with and tell us what you’ve found out from the research you’ve done so far. See How to ask a good question
